# FluentValidation - how to implement a WithMessageAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

In our .NET MVC project using FluentValidation I need to run the messages fluent validation through our translation service. This translation service asynchronously pulls the translated text from our database.

Without translation:

`RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("First name is empty!");`

With translation (*if* our translate wasn't async)

`RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty().WithMessage(_siteTextTranslationService.Translate("First name is empty!"));`

The problem is when it is async the only way I have found to do it would be:

```
When(model => model.FirstName.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), () =>
{
    RuleFor(p => p.FirstName)
        .CustomAsync(async (value, context, ct) =>
         {
             var message = await _siteTextTranslationService.Translate("First name is empty!");
             context.AddFailure(message);
         });
});
```

But this is *more* boilerplate than just not using fluent validation in the first place! Not only that we can't call much of fluent validations validation function such as `NotEmpty()`, meaning we lose out on much of the *fluent* part of fluentvalidation.

How can I asynchronously call a service translation method on fluentvalidation error messages while keeping a fluent flow, or to put it another way, how to implement a WithMessageAsync?

Comment: Do you use FluentValidation in Non-Async Middleware? If so, well, you guess it. Async is out the window, anyway. ( See warning box here: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/async.html )

Comment: And are you using `IStringLocalizer`? https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/localization.html

Comment: Hi Fildor - in this case we're injecting the `AbstractValidator<T>`s into our controllers as `IValidator<T>`. and calling `ValidateAsync` in our controller actions so we're good on that front. I'm not sure `IStringLocalizer` is a solution as we still hit the problem of needing to inject our translation service.

The only work around we can think of is to examine the `ValidationResult` after `ValidateAsync` and manually swap out the error messages with their translated versions. Hoping to avoid that!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap this boilerplate in extension method, and then use that in your fluent validation constructor.

```cs
public static class FluentValidationExtensions
{
    public static void WithMessageAsync<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> ruleBuilderOptions,
                                                      Task<string> messageTask)
    {
        ruleBuilderOptions.CustomAsync(async (_, context, _) =>
        {
            var message = await messageTask;
            context.AddFailure(message);
        });
    }
}
```

And then in your validator:

```cs
RuleFor(model => model.FirstName)
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithMessageAsync(_siteTextTranslationService.Translate("First name is empty!"));
```

Of course, you may add method overloads to support parametrized tasks, such as with cancellation token. Note that I discarded unused parameters with `_`.